# iOS Distribution on App Store. fails during submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, release

I'm totally frustrated because I'm trying already 3 days to publish an iOS App on App Store.
The app is programmed with AGK (App Game Kit: The Game Creators) and after some hours I'm successfully building a running app on the iOS simulator and an iPod.

But I'm not able to "release" it on the App Store. If I'm trying to distribute the App after "building an archive" I got this messages:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value, 'MTxxxx'. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."
>   ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'Icon-72.png'"
>   ERROR ITMS-9000: "Your Info.plist contains the UINewsstandIcon sub-property under CFBundleIcons, which is ntended for use with Newstand features. To include Newsstand features, th Info.plst must include the UINewsstandApp=true Info.plist key."

How you can see on the following picture the bundle identifier is right in the iTunes Connect (App Store entry) and in XCode 5. What is the problem?! I don't want to change it...

[Xcode build][4]
[iTunes Connect App Store][5]

I'dont have any idea what is the problem with Icon-72.png, because the file is present like all other icons and files.

If I'm trying to isolate the "build.app" and convert it locally with iTunes to .ipa I get this message via "Application Loader":

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Provisioning Profile - iOS Apps must containt a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."

Unfortunately I don't have a lot experience with iOS Development or OS X at all.

I hope you can help me. I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation for uploading all screenshots or link them.

http://www.igem-marburg.org/Files/iOS/xcode-build.jpg
http://www.igem-marburg.org/Files/iOS/iTune-Connect-AppStore.jpg

Comment: Your screenshot for xcode vs itunes-connect for bundle identifier doesn't show us your Bundle Identifier in xcode -> Go to your target -> General and the first line under Identity is Bundle Identifier. What does that say?

Comment: Just the other screenshot:
http://www.igem-marburg.org/Files/iOS/xcode-general.jpg

It shows up the same bundle identifier :'(

Comment: if you don't mind can you verify your info.plist ? that is cmd+o type info.plist and see whether your values are correct over there ? (bundle identifier)

Comment: It seems to be right (or not?)
http://www.igem-marburg.org/Files/iOS/info.plist.jpg

Comment: As I see I really used a wrong bundle identifier on the App-Store.
But maybe some has suggestion what's wrong about the missing (exsisting file)? I even don't use the Newsstand..

Comment: I had the same error for the newsstand icon. To fix it, I opened my info.plist file and in there, under CFBundleIcons, I found UINewsstandIcon. I deleted this and re-archived my project and it was accepted.